# Attempting to use equalTo on Firebase Realtime Database query

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following node:

```
attendanceOptions: {
uid1: 'blah@example.com',
uid2: 'tap@example.com'
}
```

I'm trying to return only the key and value where value is equal to.  These are my two attempts.

```
  const getMinistry = await admin.database().ref(`organization/${req.orgId}/attendanceOptions`)
  getMinistry
    .equalTo(req.memberUid)
    .once('value', snapshot => {
      functions.logger.log(snapshot.val())
    });
```

This returns null
I also tried:

```
  const getMinistry = await admin.database().ref(`organization/${req.orgId}`)
  getMinistry
    .orderByChild('attendanceOptions')
    .equalTo(req.memberUid)
    .once('value', snapshot => {
      const data = snapshot.val();
      functions.logger.log( `this is data: ${data}` )
      return data;
    });
```

The log is `this is data: null`

In my rules I have:

```
"attendanceOptions": {
  ".indexOn": [".value"]
},
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
getMinistry
  .child('attendanceOptions')
  .orderByValue()
  .equalTo(req.memberUid)
```